# Не работает Static API Yandex карт

Tags: yandex-static-maps-api

Пытаюсь получить карту по элементарному запросу

```
https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?ll=56.5203533,85.052161&l=map
```

но получаю какую-то непонятную пустоту

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Координаты реальные, из жизни. Пробовал разные варианты - и с зумом, и всяко-разно. В документации говорят, что обязательный параметр только 1 - тип карты (`l=map`), но если указать только его - возвращается такая же пустота.  В чём дело?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неверно указали порядок "долгота, широта" как описано в [документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/staticapi/1.x/dg/concepts/map_viewport-docpage/):

```
https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?ll=85.052161,56.5203533&l=map
```